# Issues with ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse when proxying to localhost and a different TCP port

Tags: reverse-proxy, httpd, selinux, proxypass

I am attempting to use ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse to proxy requests through Apache to another server instance that is bound to the localhost on a different TCP port that the Vhost exists (VHost is bound to :80, when the target is bound to :5000).

However, I am repeatedly receiving HTTP 503 when accessing the Location.

According to the [ProxyPass documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName apacheserver.domain.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/redmine/public
    ErrorLog logs/redmine_error

    <Directory /var/www/redmine/public>
            Allow from all
            Options -MultiViews
            Order allow,deny
            AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
PassengerTempDir /tmp/passenger

<Location /rhodecode>
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:5000/rhodecode
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:5000/rhodecode
  SetEnvIf X-Url-Scheme https HTTPS=1
</Location>
```

I have tested binding the alternate server to the interface IP address, and the same issue occurs.

The server servicing request is an instance of python paste:httpserver, and it has been configured to use the /rhodecode suffix (as I saw this to be mentioned in other posts about ProxyPass).  The [documentation from the project itself](http://packages.python.org/RhodeCode/setup.html#apache-as-subdirectory), Rhodecode, reports to use the above.

The issue is persistent if I target another server that is serving on a different port.

Does ProxyPass allow proxying to a different TCP port?

**[update]**

I won't delete this, in case someone comes across the same issue.

I had set an ErrorLog, and in that ErrorLog the following error was reported:

```
[Wed Nov 09 11:36:35 2011] [error] (13)Permission denied: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:5000 (192.168.100.100) failed
[Wed Nov 09 11:36:35 2011] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (192.168.100.100)
```

After some more research, I attempted to set SELinux to permissive (`echo 0 >/selinux/enforce`), and try again.

It turns out the SELinux boolean `httpd_can_network_connect` must be set to `1`.

For persistence on reboot:

`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1`

Comment: If you connect to http://127.0.0.1:5000/rhodecode directly do you get a response?

Comment: Yes, I have tested this with `lynx` on the local machine.

Comment: Seems like it could be related to SELinux.  I will changed to permissive and attempt again

Answer (score 5):

A nicer way to fix this (to have your cake and eat it) with regards to SELinux is to run this command to make httpd_t types aware of the port you are using..

```
semanage port -a -p tcp -t http_port_t 5000
```

You can turn off that boolean then and still get it to work.

Comment: Thanks man.  I spotted that boolean on [this manpage on die.net](http://linux.die.net/man/8/httpd_selinux).  It indicates: `SELinux policy can be setup such that httpd scripts are not allowed to connect out to the network. This would prevent a hacker from breaking into you httpd server and attacking other machines. If you need scripts to be able to connect you can set the httpd_can_network_connect boolean on.`  I believe the "httpd scripts are not allowed to connect out to the network" is a default policy.  Meaning, regardless of the port policy, wouldn't this boolean also have to be set to 1?

Comment: Well, I had to perform `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1`, just tuning the port label didn't do it. Fedora 29.

Comment: Matthrex, @DavidTonhofer - adding the port to `http_port_t` only works if a SE-boolean that guards `http_port_t` usage is enabled, as well - such us `httpd_can_network_relay`.  Note that `httpd_can_network_relay` is disabled, by default - and that it also guards some other port labels such as `http_cache_port_t`. Enabling `httpd_can_network_connect` always works because it allows connections to any port. Thus the advantage of using something else is to have less ports reachable from a compromised http server.

Comment: Seems on EL7 and EL8 there are a few booleans that control it which are on by default. ```[root@scratch-el8 ~]# sesearch -s httpd_t --allow -t http_port_t -p name_connect
allow httpd_t http_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect; [ httpd_can_network_relay ]:True
allow httpd_t http_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect; [ httpd_graceful_shutdown ]:True
allow httpd_t port_type:tcp_socket name_connect; [ httpd_can_network_connect ]:True
allow nsswitch_domain reserved_port_type:tcp_socket name_connect; [ nis_enabled ]:True``` In particular ```httpd_graceful_shutdown```